# bash ng command not found mac

Tags: macos, angular-cli

**bash ng** command not found mac 
ng serve works for me only the time when I just installed

**ng serve** works for me only the time when I just installed, after that I opened new terminal and after navigating to the angular project directory and try to run '**ng serve**' at that time the terminal is showing 'bash **ng command** not found'

Comment: same thing is happening when I tried to 'reat-native run-android' , at that time  terminal is showing
' -bash: react-native: command not found ' ,
but when I installed react-native for first time this command works for me

Answer (score 1):

Works well for me
1. Link cli to npm: npm link @angular/cli

2. Set the location of npm folder: export PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
3. Clear cache and re-install cli:
   npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   npm cache clean
   npm install -g @angular/cli
4. Give alias to ng path : alias ng="/Users/Dharshini/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
5. Go back to the base user: cd ~
6. Change path using vim: sudo vim /etc/paths
7. Add ~/.npm-global/bin to the end of the file.
   type i to insert 
   type :wq to save and exit
8. restart terminal and type: echo $PATH
9. Finally know the version using: ng version

Answer (score 1):

For solving this issue

```
-bash: ng: command not found
```

you need to set PATH, follow these steps and you'll be good to go:

1. Set the location for npm Folder, Run any one of them:

> ```
> export PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
> export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
> ```

2. Clear cache and Re-install Angular

> ```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> npm cache clean 
> npm install -g @angular/cli
> ```

3. Give an alias to ng Path-

   PATH = /Users/Dharshini/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> ```
> alias ng="PATH"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Node modules resides in the directory /opt/node/bin

Add these two lines to your .bashrc file
NODE_BIN="/opt/node/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$NODE_BIN"

Save and close .bashrc and run: source .bashrc

....
Currently, both node and npm runs without being referenced in .bashrc, but that is because the executable files for node and npm are located in /usr/local/bin directory which itself is by default on the $PATH. So, instead of adding the 'ng' executable to /usr/local/bin, I exported /opt/node/bin to my path instead, to prevent any other modules in the future from not being found.